# How can I prevent a component from rendering before data is loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am waiting the props to come up from a store named `GetDealersStore`, and the way I am fetching that data is with an action where I am doing this:

```
  componentWillMount () { GetDealersActions.getDealers(); }
```

I already test the app and `componentWillMount()` is running before the initial render where I have this

```
let dealerInfo;
if (this.state.dealerData) {
  dealerInfo = this.state.dealerData.dealersData.map((dealer) => {
    return (<div>CONTENT</div>);
  })
} else {
  dealerInfo = <p>Loading . . .</p>
}
```

but for the first second you can see `<p>Loading . . .</p>` in the screen which is the `else` in the conditional above, and then the rest of the render comes up with `return (<div>CONTENT</div>);` which is the `if` in the conditional. So, I guess, this means that the render method has been trigger twice because it keeps waiting for the data coming from the database.

The data from the database is not available at the time of the 1st render, so, how can I fetch that data before the 1st initial render occurs?

Comment: @Mathletics "nonsense" only because you don't understand it ? I am just a junior developer asking for help. I have tried everything and still don't get it. So sorry, if I bother you, you can ignore the question. EASY!

Comment: @Mathletics I already debug it, the whole problem I have is that the data from the databse is not available at the time of the 1st render, so, how can I fetch that data before the 1st initial rendering occurs? can you explain me that ?

Comment: You can't do that from within a component. Remember, the job of React is to RENDER a component; if you have nothing to render, you shouldn't call the component in the first place.

Comment: Use getInitialState to default state so that state is created and the render method will not fail. Then this shouldn't be an issue. And, I'd recommend giving https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html a read if you haven't already.

Comment: @Mathletics OK, if you read the question, there I have a conditional for when I don't have data. Can you tell me, how to fetch the data before the 1st render occurs? Who should complete that task then ? the stores ? the actions ?

Comment: __You cannot block the initial render.__ Use a [container component](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005) to manage your data and render when ready.

Comment: @JeffSiver the render method doesn't fail; it (correctly) renders the _Loading..._ block, since no data is loaded. OP is asking how to prevent the no-data scenario.

Comment: @JeffSiver seems as if you haven't read the question. `componentWillMount` is trigger properly, before the 1st render. But the data from the database is not available before the 1st render. So if I use any other type of Lifecycle method, the app crashes.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend simplifying your question. There is a lot of code here and much of it does not seem related to your question though I'm not really sure. Having said that, if you can come up with a simpler example of the problem you are having, it will be much easier for us to help you find a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really get that out of the question. And, as @Mathletics stated, you cannot block the initial render.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do this with a single component. You should follow the [Container Component](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005) pattern to separate data from rendering.

```
let DealersContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {dealersData: []};
  },
  componentWillMount() {
    GetDealersActions.getDealers();
  },
  render() {
    let {dealersData} = this.state;
    return (<div>
      {dealersData.map((dealer) => {
        let props = dealer;
        return (<Dealer ...props />); // pass in dealerData as PROPS here
      })}
    </div>);
  }
});
```

Then update your `Dealer` component to receive props and render the actual content.

Comment: according to some other people, there is a way to do this with `state` in order to update the component by itself, the people at my office keep telling me: don't use state, only props.

Comment: You SHOULD use `props` as much as possible, but `props` must be passed in from the parent component. This pattern allows you to have exactly one stateful component and the rest deal only with props.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer See here for an extension of what Mathletics is referring to - "smart vs dumb components" - https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Answer (score 8):

My answer is similar to Mathletics', just in more detail.

In this example I've included initialising state of dealerData to null; this is the check that's made to determine whether the data has been returned from the store by the container.

It's verbose, but declarative, and does what you want, in the order that you want, and it will work each time.

```
const DealerStore = MyDataPersistenceLibrary.createStore({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      dealerData: null
    };
  },

  getDealers() {
    // some action that sets the dealerData to an array
  }
});

const DealerInfoContainer = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount() {
    DealerStoreActions.getDealers();
  },

  _renderDealerInfo() {
    return (
      <DealerInfo {...this.state} />
    );
  },

  _renderLoader() {
    return (
      <p>Loading...</p>
    );
  },

  render() {
    const { dealerData } = this.state;

    return (
      dealerData
      ? this._renderDealerInfo()
      : this._renderLoader()
    );
  }
});

const DealerInfo = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      dealerData: []
    };
  },

  _renderDealers() {
    const { dealerData } = this.props;

    return dealerData.map(({ name }, index) => <div key={index}>{name}</div>);
  },

  _renderNoneFound() {
    return (
      <p>No results to show!</p>
    );
  },

  render() {
    const { dealerData } = this.props;

    return (
      dealerData.length 
      ? this._renderDealers()
      : this._renderNoneFound()
    );
  }
});
```